# How to add Image or any field on Calendars section for Solspace Calendar?

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

How to add Image or any field on Calendars section for Solspace Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You'd do it from the Calendar's field layout page (https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendars/), just like Craft entries, users, categories, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to adding extra fields to what a calendar itself contains (for displaying additional content with [Calendar object](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar/)), then that currently is not possible. Only the built in options are available.